# Assign CSS for all tables except one

Tags: css

In my CSS I have:

```
table {
Width:100%;
max-width:600px;
}
```

Thisobviously assigns the above CSS to every table on the site but how can I make it not assign to just on table throughout the whole site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS [:not() Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot).

Here's an example for a selector for all tables except for a table with an ID of `#uniqueTableID`

```
table:not(#uniqueTableID) {
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
}
```

Notice this have some browser compatibility issues:

```
Feature         Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)         Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
Basic support   1.0     1.0 (1.7 or earlier)    9.0                 9.5     3.2
```

---

> **Summary**
>
> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.

Comment: While this will work (where :not is supported), I usually recommend "positive selectors" to mitigate impacts of future changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support older browsers, one option would be to give your special table an id (or class) and then override the default table styles from your stylesheet. For example:

```
#special-table {
  display:table;
  width:auto;
  max-width:none;
  ...
}
```